# Keep Bootstrap dropdown open on click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use a bootstrap dropdown as a shoppingcart. In the shopping cart is a 'remove product' button (a link). If I click it, my shoppingcart script removes the product, but the menu fades away. Is there anyway way to prevent this? I tried e.startPropagation, but that didn't seem to work:

```
<div id="shoppingcart" class="nav-collapse cart-collapse">
 <ul class="nav pull-right">
  <li class="dropdown open">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Totaal:
    &acirc;&sbquo;&not; 43,00</a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="nav-header">Pakketten</li>

      <li>
       <span class="quantity">1x</span>
       <span class="product-name">Test Product </span>
       <span class="product-remove"><a class="removefromcart" packageid="4" href="#">x</a>
        </span></li>

      <li><a href="#">Total: &euro; 43,00</a></li>

      <li><a href="/checkout">Checkout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see tha  element with class="dropwdown-toggle" made it a dropdown. Another idea was that I just reopen it on clicking programmatically. So if someone can explain me how to programmatically open a Bootstrap dropdown, it would help well!

Comment: I see you already have an answer, but there is a much simpler way. Just wrap the contents of the menu in a form tag. That's it.
So, instead of `ul.dropdown-menu`, use `form.dropdown-menu>ul`.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Try removing the propagation on the button itself like so:

```
$('.dropdown-menu a.removefromcart').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Edit**

Here is a demo from the comments with the solution above:

http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/E9mpu/

Relevant code:

**JS**

```
$(".removefromcart").on("click", function(e){
    var fadeDelete = $(this).parents('.product');
    $(fadeDelete).fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });

    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="shoppingcart" class="nav-collapse cart-collapse">
 <ul class="nav pull-right">
  <li class="dropdown open">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Totaal:
    &acirc;&sbquo;&not; 43,00</a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="nav-header">Pakketten</li>
        <li class="product">
            <span class="product-remove"><a class="removefromcart" packageid="2" href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></span>
            <span class="product-name">Test Product </span>
            <span class="quantity"><span class="badge badge-inverse">1</span></span>
        </li>
        <li class="product">
            <span class="product-remove"><a class="removefromcart" packageid="2" href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></span>
            <span class="product-name">Test Product </span>
            <span class="quantity"><span class="badge badge-inverse">10</span></span>
        </li>
        <li class="product">
            <span class="product-remove"><a class="removefromcart" packageid="2" href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></span>
            <span class="product-name">Test Product </span>
            <span class="quantity"><span class="badge badge-inverse">8</span></span>
        </li>
        <li class="product">
            <span class="product-remove"><a class="removefromcart" packageid="2" href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></span>
            <span class="product-name">Test Product </span>
            <span class="quantity"><span class="badge badge-inverse">3</span></span>
        </li>
        <li class="product">
            <span class="product-remove"><a class="removefromcart" packageid="2" href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></span>
            <span class="product-name">Test Product </span>
            <span class="quantity"><span class="badge badge-inverse">4</span></span>
        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Total: &euro; 43,00</a></li>
        <li><a href="/checkout">Checkout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Okay, this works, but now the remove button is not working anymore, which I could 've thought of my self. So probably I DO need to programmatically re-open the div. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @MartenSytema that all depends on how you're removing the products from the menu, but take this for example: http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/E9mpu/, notice how i implemented the `.stopPropagation()` method along with the removal script.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! The only problem is there that I need to use the live jquery method to bind the click event, and as jQuery says: _Since the .live() method handles events once they have propagated to the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of live events._ [link](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: @MartenSytema both methods do the same thing. Also,  [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated as of jQuery version 1.7.

Comment: @MartenSytema forgot to mention, `.live()` was replaced by `.on()`.

Comment: So, does the fact that the items are generated by JS and thus are 'live' make that this implementation does not work in my case, but does work when the DOM is already there on page load?

Comment: @MartenSytema i'm not sure i understand what you mean. If you're asking that if the `.on()` event handler will still attach to your js-embedded objects then yes, it will, just like `.live()` will, they are the same thing and both have the same functionality.

Comment: You understand me correctly, but somehow when I use 'on' the handler is not called at all, where as if i change on to 'live' it IS called.

Comment: @MartenSytema on the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) documentation page they have a section where you can see how to properly convert from `.live()` to `.on()`, i'm working blindly here so i suggest you go over that and then comeback with some code. Here is the proper setup for the `.on()` method: `$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler); `, it should work out of the box, there is nothing that should be stopping it from working aside from an improper setup.

Comment: Thank you, i read on the on() page that i should use delegated events. Now it works. Huge thanks!

Comment: The fiddle no longer seems to work. Any way to fix it?

Comment: but my link have #archor. How can I prevent it added in to url?

Answer (score 37):

On bootstrap 4, when you put a form inside the dropdown menu, it won't collapse when clicking inside of it.

So this worked best for me:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <!-- toggle button/link -->
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <form>
            <!-- content -->
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't know how but this does work and should be the top answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for actually providing an answer that doesn't use jQuery! Works like a charm.

Comment: This did it for me so easily. Thank you.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: For me this seems to keep it open if *some* items are clicked but not all. I have a list of <li>s with checkboxes and labels and if I click on the checkbox it stays open, but if I click on the label it closes.

Answer (score 36):

This answer is just a sidenote to the accepted answer. Thanks to both the OP and Andres for this Q & A, it solved my problem.  Later, however, I needed something that worked with dynamically added items in my dropdown. Anyone coming across this one might also be interested in a variation Andres' solution that works both with the initial elements as well as elements added to the dropdown after the page has loaded:

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.dropdown-menu").on("click", "[data-keepOpenOnClick]", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Or, for dynamically created dropdown menus:

```
$(document).delegate("ul.dropdown-menu [data-keepOpenOnClick]", "click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Then just put the `data-keepOpenOnClick` attribute anywhere in any of the `<li>` tags or its child elements, depending on your situation.  E.G.:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <-- EG 1: Do not close when clicking on the link -->
        <a href="#" data-keepOpenOnClick>
            ...
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <-- EG 2: Do not close when clicking the checkbox -->
        <input type="checkbox" data-keepOpenOnClick> Pizza
    </li>

    <-- EG 3: Do not close when clicking the entire LI -->
    <li data-keepOpenOnClick>
        ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 17):

In short, You can try this. It is working for me.

```
<span class="product-remove">
  <a class="removefromcart" onclick=" event.stopPropagation();" packageid="4" href="#">x</a>
  </span>
```

Answer (score 5):

The menu opens when you give `show` class to the menu, so you can implement the function yourself without using `data-toggle="dropdown"`.

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

```css
#overlay{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
}

#overlay.show{
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu{
  z-index: 1001;
}
```

```js
$('button, #overlay').on('click', function(){
  $('.dropdown-menu, #overlay').toggleClass('show')
})
```

Try this in [codepen](https://codepen.io/masamoto-miyata/pen/eQEENE).

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem with an accordion/toggle sub-menu that was nested within a dropdown-menu in Bootstrap 3. Borrowed this syntax from the [source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/dropdown.js#L149) to stop all collapse toggles from closing the dropdown:

```
$(document).on(
    'click.bs.dropdown.data-api', 
    '[data-toggle="collapse"]', 
    function (e) { e.stopPropagation() }
);
```

You can replace `[data-toggle="collapse"]` with whatever you want to stop closing the form, similar to how @DonamiteIsTnt added a property to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some lines of code that make it works as perfect as we need with more of control on it:

```
$(".dropdown_select").on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
    if($(this).attr("keep-open") == "true") {
        $(this).addClass("open");
        $(this).removeAttr("keep-open");
    }
});

$(".dropdown_select ul li").bind("click", function (e) {
    // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT
    $(".dropdown_select").attr("keep-open", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From Bootstrap 5, There is a setting for this in the options: `data-bs-auto-close="outside"`.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/dropdowns/#auto-close-behavior