# Checkbox dropdown won't stay down in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I figured out how to make a checkbox dropdown without using custom Javascript other than the bootstrap library for the dropdown button. No Javascript for handling the form data.:

http://plnkr.co/edit/NOM0UK2io6LaiJE5aSbs?p=preview

I have implemented this in an ASP-MVC view, but the behavior id different. In the ASP-MVC version, the dropdown pops back up after each checkbox selection. It's very annoying.

The ASP-MVC code is just the `container` div and its contents. [Here](http://localhost:52459/DropdownTest) is a live example, for as long as it stays up.

**HTML + Bootstrap:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">

    <form action="http://yahoo.com" method="get" target="_blank">

      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Checkboxes
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
          <li role="presentation"><input type="checkbox" name="cx1">cx1</li>
          <li role="presentation"><input type="checkbox" name="cx2">cx2</li>
          <li role="presentation"><input type="checkbox" name="cx3">cx3</li>
          <li role="presentation"><input type="checkbox" name="cx4">cx4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default">

    </form>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="container">

    <form action="http://yahoo.com" method="get" target="_blank">

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Checkboxes
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                <li role="presentation"><input type="checkbox" name="cx1" data-stoppropagation="true">cx1</li>
                <li role="presentation"><input type="checkbox" name="cx2" data-stoppropagation="true">cx2</li>
                <li role="presentation"><input type="checkbox" name="cx3" data-stoppropagation="true">cx3</li>
                <li role="presentation"><input type="checkbox" name="cx4" data-stoppropagation="true">cx4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default">

    </form>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("ul.dropdown-menu").on("click", "[data-stopPropagation]", function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
</script>



@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("ul.dropdown-menu").on("click", "[data-stopPropagation]", function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
    </script>
}
```

**EDIT: offending Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getSpeciesList();

});

var current_path = window.location.pathname;
var current_controller = current_path.split('/')[1];

var species_select_url = "/" + current_controller + "/fillSpeciesSelect";

function getSpeciesList() {
    console.log("in get species list");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url, // the method we are calling
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "",
        success: function (result) {
            //alert("successfully got species list");
            //alert(result[0]["SpeciesName"]);
            fillSpeciesList(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            //alert('Oh no aa :(' + result[0]);
        }

    })
}

function fillSpeciesList(species_list) {
    console.log(species_list[0]["SpeciesName"]);
    var species_select = $('.rreport-species-select');
    for (var i = 0 ; i < species_list.length ; i++) {
        //alert(species_list[i]["SpeciesName"]);
        console.log(species_list[i]["SpeciesName"]);
        species_select.append
        (
            "<li role='presentation'>" +
            "<input type='checkbox' " +
            "name='" + species_list[i]['SpeciesId'] + "' " + 
            "data-stoppropagation='true'" + 
            ">" + species_list[i]['SpeciesName'] + "</li>" +
            "</option>"
        );
    }

}

$('#species-select').on('change', function () {
    var species_id = $('.report-species-select').val();
    $('#variety-select').empty();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/" + current_controller + "/fillVarietiesSelect", // the method we are calling
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { "species_id": species_id },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            fillVarietiesList(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Oh no aa :(' + result[0]);
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to this answer [Keep DropDown Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480697/keep-bootstrap-dropdown-open-on-click)

Try this:

1. Add Script tag to whatever view you're working on

   `$(function () {
           $("ul.dropdown-menu").on("click", "[data-stopPropagation]", function (e) {
               e.stopPropagation();
           });
       });`
2. As per the accepted answer add data-stoppropagation="true" to every checkbox element.

   `<input type="checkbox" name="cx1" data-stoppropagation="true">cx1</li>`

Comment: Hmmm. Works when I ONLY have that javascript. When I include the linked javascript file (necessary), it doesn't work.

Comment: Based on your Javascript I dont see an element that matches $('.rreport-species-select');...Which element is that supposed to be? If you open your developer tools in IE or Chrome it will tell you if your javascript has an error that stops it from running

Comment: Ack! You are right. That extra "r" was killing the Javascript execution. It works now!