# do not hide HTML dropdown(<select>) on selecting disabled option

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a html dropdown(selectbox) with some disabled values in my html&angular code. when I click on a disabled value, it hides the dropdown. is it possible to show the dropdown even when the disabled option is clicked. I have searched it around but I couldn't find any solution. is this possible?
[image: selectbox]

I have multiple disabled options.

Answer (score 1):

I would add another class name to the list item and test otherwise you will need to use conditional logic to remove the link from the list item when the class disabled is loaded.

Comment: how to control that with a class? can you please explain me your idea a littile brief.

Comment: If you use CSS you can give the list item a class name and code it so it does not close on click, but when I say conditional logic, you can also use javascript to keep it open, see [this question's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480697/keep-bootstrap-dropdown-open-on-click) answer

Comment: I'm not using links here. I use <select></select> box. I'm asking about this disabled option.

Comment: look at what @shi said, this is what I mean... it closes because of the class you use in CSS, you need to change/add/remove the class.

Comment: please add your code to question so we can review better

Answer (score 1):

If you use `:hover` in your CSS remove it, it should fix it.

Comment: I should not remove that, when I click that disabled option the dropdown should not close.