# Bootstrap 4 Toggle Checkbox within Dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I placed a checkbox styled with Bootstrap Toggle Plugin (http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) in a Bootstrap 4 dropdown menu (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/). When I click the toggle, the menu gets closed immediately.

I can prevent this by using `onclick="event.stopPropagation();"` on the menu item (code from here: [Keep Bootstrap dropdown open on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480697/keep-bootstrap-dropdown-open-on-click)). But then, the toggle switch does not work anymore.

Is there a way to have the menu stay open when the toggle is clicked?

Comment: Can you show your work on a fiddle/so snippet ?

Answer (score 1):

if you wrap your toggle inside a form-tag it should not close the dropdown.

http://jsfiddle.net/mjhr0f6d/2/

```
...
<form>
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">wrapped inside form
</form>
...
```

Comment: When I use `<li>`elements, my menu gets messed up. I have to use `<a>`or `span` and then this solution does not work. I am using Bootstrap4

Comment: @Mario i'm sorry, it was the wrong link. Now the example should work.